# How load Database Contents to ajax in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm trying load price column from database to ajax file using asp.net C#. is it possible? is there any other way??

```
function addProduct() {
    //this is just a product placeholder
    //you should insert an item with the selected product info
    //replace productId, productName, price and url with your real product info


    productId = productId + 1;
    var productAdded = $('<li class="product"><div class="product-image"><a href="#0"><img src="img/product-preview.png" alt="placeholder"></a></div><div class="product-details"><h3><a href="#0">Product Name</a></h3><span class="price">$25.99</span><div class="actions"><a href="#0" class="delete-item">Delete</a><div class="quantity"><label for="cd-product-'+ productId +'">Qty</label><span class="select"><select id="cd-product-'+ productId +'" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option></select></span></div></div></div></li>');
    cartList.prepend(productAdded);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate more, it is not clear what your problem is or what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: i want to load item price which is stored in database to this div. which is in this ajax function. how do i do it?

Comment: basically this a cart system if user clicks a button. button will pass these price and product name to cart box. So here i want load these price and name  column dynamically from database. using asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load it in Ajax, you should have a backend service to serve your request, assuming that it exist and its URL is /Product/GetProductInfo, then your code should be like:

```
function addProduct(productId) {
    //this is just a product placeholder
    //you should insert an item with the selected product info
    //replace productId, productName, price and url with your real product info

   $.ajax('/Product/GetProductInfo?productId='+productId,function(data){

    var productAdded = $('<li class="product"><div class="product-image"><a href="#0"><img src="'+data.productImageUrl+'" alt="placeholder"></a></div><div class="product-details"><h3><a href="#0">'+data.productName+'/a></h3><span class="price">$'+data.price+'</span><div class="actions"><a href="#0" class="delete-item">Delete</a><div class="quantity"><label for="cd-product-'+ productId +'">Qty</label><span class="select"><select id="cd-product-'+ productId +'" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option></select></span></div></div></div></li>');
    cartList.prepend(productAdded);
});
}
```

In your button, it should call the `addProduct` passing the product id, ex:

```
<button onclick='addProduct(4)'>Add to Cart</button>
```

Your backend should accept the query string paramter productId and return an object that has the product information like product name, price, image ...